# The fractional part of $n\log(n)$

Tags: continued-fractions, visualization, fractional-part

When I was thinking about my [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1892135/about-a-mysterious-sequence-who-seems-to-follow-some-patterns) on the sequence

$$p(n)=\min_a\left\{a+b,\ \left\lfloor\frac {2^a}{3^b}\right\rfloor=n\right\}$$

I found an interesting link with the sequence

$$q(n)=\{n\log(n)\}=n\log(n)-[n\log(n)]$$

the fractional part of $n\log(n)$.

If we draw the sequence $q$, we get this (for $n$ up to $520$, $5\,000$ and $30\,000$ respectively):

[image]

[image]

[image]

We can see some *gaps* looking like parabolas.

> What is causing those gaps? Why do they look like this?

In my [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1892135/about-a-mysterious-sequence-who-seems-to-follow-some-patterns), we can observe similar structures:

[image]

An answer is telling me that it is due to the continued fraction of $\log2/\log 3$.

> Could the two questions be linked?

---

**Edit.**

Thanks to Gottfried Helms idea, here is some more drawings with the moduli varying.

The moduli will take those values respectively:

$$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100.$$

A modulus of $1$ corresponding to the fractional part.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to take other moduli instead of $\pmod 1$, for instance $\pmod 2$ or $\pmod 10$? Perhaps the parabolas become even more prominent?

Answer (score 6):

While this is not a complete answer, in order to get some insight to this phenomenon, consider the expression
$$\{q(n+1)-q(n)\}=\{(n+1)\log(n+1)-n\log(n)\}=\{n\log(1+\frac{1}{n})+\log(n+1)\}$$
The first summand $n\log(1+\frac{1}{n})\sim 1-\frac{1}{2n}$ which is almost an integer and doesn't affect too much on that expression. It follows that $\{q(n+1)-q(n)\}\sim\{\log(n+1)\}$.
So if $n+1\sim e^k$ or equivalently $\log(n+1)\sim k$ then the difference above is almost zero. You can see this in your diagram at $e^4\sim 54, e^5 \sim 148, e^5 \sim 403$ which is the bottom of the "parabolas". A little bit before it $\{q(n+1)-q(n)\}\sim\{\log(n+1)\}$ is a little bit smaller than 1 so that your graph is monotone decreasing, and similarly after it the graph is monotone increasing.

If for example $n+1\sim e^{5.5}\sim 255$ then the difference above is more or less 1/2 and then you will see two "parabolas" one above the other. The same argument will work for $n\sim e^{k +\frac{p}{q}}$ when you fix the rational $\frac{p}{q}$.

Answer (score 3):

***Not an answer*** but some more illustration (by my own couriosity)

I*ve looked at your function mod 10 and 100. Nice pictures... 
[image: mod 10]

[image: mod 100]

Ok, just for fun: "fine wood". Also see, how the picture can nicely be stacked vertically; here I stacked the mod-100 picture 3 times:
[image: finewood mod 100]

Comment: Great illustrations! I wonder what it would look like in 3D if the moduli varied